# How to find the index of the first char in a string that is not in a list

Tags: c#, string, search

I know I can loop over the string or build a regex or invert the set (ASCII isn't that big after all) and search for the first instance of that, but Yuck.

What I'm looking for is a nice one liner.

fewer features is better, LINQ is out (for me, don't ask, it's a *long* story)

---

The solution I'm going with (unless I see something better)

```
static int FirstNotMeta(int i, string str)
{
    for(; i < str.Length; i++)
        switch(str[i])
        {
            case '\\':
            case '/':
            case '.':
                continue;
            default:
                return i;
        }
    return -1;
}
```

OK, I cheated, I know in advance what char's I care about.

Comment: The app needs to run on Linux without mono, so I'm also doing an auto translation to a language that doesn't need mono.   Oh, boy am I having fun! Really, I am!

Comment: Should have said you want the index and not the character.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works:

```
public static char FindFirstNotAny(this string value, params char[] charset)
{
    return value.TrimStart(charset)[0];
}
```

Comment: "nest": a word describing the condition of having bad aim on key boards and thinking something is cool

Comment: @BCS: I should have read all the way to the end of your definition! nice one! i..e very nest

Comment: Nice, didn't even think of that. Make sure there IS a character at 0 though.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have access to LINQ, I think you may just have to write a static method with a loop (which is probably more efficient than LINQ anyway. Remember the compiler will inline small methods when possible.

The simplest non-LINQ I can come up with is below. I recommend adding braces so scope and the blocks are clear:

```
public static char? GetFirstChar(string str, char[] list)
{
    foreach (char c in str) if (!list.Contains(c)) return c;
    return null;
}
```

With C# 3.0 and LINQ:

```
char[] list = { 'A', 'B' };
string str = "AABAGAF";

char first = str.ToArray().Where(c => !list.Contains(c)).FirstOrDefault();
```

In that case, if there is no non-list character, first will equal 0x0000 (or the *character* null). You could do this:

```
char? first = str.ToArray().Cast<char?>().Where(
    c => !list.Contains(c.Value)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Then first will be null if there are no matches. This can also be written as:

```
var query = from char c in str
            where !list.Contains(c)
            select (char?)c;
char? first = query.FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

Not all that efficient, but:

```
char f(string str, IEnumerable<char> list)
{
  return str.ToCharArray().First(c => !list.Contains(c))
}
```

Comment: Won't this return the value of the first char, not the index?

Answer (score 1):

Will this C/C++ example work for you:

```
char *strToSearch = "This is the one liner you want"
char *skipChars = "Tthise";
size_f numToSkip = strcspn(strToSearch, skipChars);
```

The `strcspn()` function scans a string for the complement of the specified set.  It returns the number of initial characters that do *not* include a character in the set.

Comment: It'd seem the code behind strcspn would be what's needed...GPL version: http://www.google.com/codesearch?hl=en&q=strcspn()+show:q-MgOPi_2MA:rmZVXVSA8yk:TmTxHZwPCms&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc&cs_p=ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gettext/gettext-0.13.tar.gz&cs_f=gettext-0.13/gettext-tools/lib/strcspn.c